# Pinch for ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, pinchzoom

I have imageView. I need to use pinch for imageView. I referred some documents. But everything used doubleTap. When use doubleTap zoomIn and ZoomOut. I dn't want doubltTap ZoomIn and out. I need to use fingers for pinch. I used OnTouch for imageView moving.

code:

Touch class:

```
package com.example.blogactivity;

import android.graphics.Matrix;  
import android.graphics.PointF;  
import android.util.FloatMath;  
import android.view.MotionEvent;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;  
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Touch implements OnTouchListener{

    // These matrices will be used to move and zoom image  
     Matrix matrix = new Matrix();  
     Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();  

     // We can be in one of these 3 states  
     static final int NONE = 0;  
     static final int DRAG = 1;  
     static final int ZOOM = 2;  
     int mode = NONE;  

     // Remember some things for zooming  
     PointF start = new PointF();  
     PointF mid = new PointF();  
     float oldDist = 1f;  


     @Override  
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {  
      ImageView view = (ImageView) v;  
      // Dump touch event to log  
      dumpEvent(event);  

      // Handle touch events here...  
      switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {  
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:  
       savedMatrix.set(matrix);  
       start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());  
       mode = DRAG;  
       break;  
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:  
       oldDist = spacing(event);  
       if (oldDist > 10f) {  
        savedMatrix.set(matrix);  
        midPoint(mid, event);  
        mode = ZOOM;  
       }  
       break;  
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:  
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:  
       mode = NONE;  
       break;  
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:  
       if (mode == DRAG) {  
        // ...      
        matrix.set(savedMatrix);  
        matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);      
       } else if (mode == ZOOM) {  
        float newDist = spacing(event);  
        if (newDist > 10f) {  
         matrix.set(savedMatrix);  
         float scale = newDist / oldDist;  
         matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);  
        }  
       }  
       break;  
      }  

      view.setImageMatrix(matrix);  
      return true; // indicate event was handled  
     }  

     /** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */  
     private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {  
      String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",  
        "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };  
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
      int action = event.getAction();  
      int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;  
      sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);  
      if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN  
        || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {  
       sb.append("(pid ").append(  
         action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);  
       sb.append(")");  
      }  
      sb.append("[");  
      for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {  
       sb.append("#").append(i);  
       sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));  
       sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));  
       sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));  
       if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())  
        sb.append(";");  
      }  
      sb.append("]");  
     }  



     private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {  
      float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);  
      float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);  
      return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);  
     }  


     private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {  
      float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);  
      float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);  
      point.set(x / 2, y / 2);  
     }  


}
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.blogactivity;

import com.example.blogactivity.*;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class BlogActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_blog);

        image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        image.setOnTouchListener(new Touch()); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.blog, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".BlogActivity" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"  
       android:layout_width="match_parent"  
       android:layout_height="match_parent"  
       android:src="@drawable/butterfly"  
       android:scaleType="matrix"  
       android:adjustViewBounds="true"  
       android:layout_gravity="center" />  


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use [PhotoView](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/photoview/) and save yourself the trouble.

Comment: try this [Android ImageView: Zoom in Zoom out And Drag](http://vmustafayev4en.blogspot.tw/2011/12/android-imageview-zoom-in-zoom-out.html)

Comment: @Drag: I used that code inside my app. It's not working

Comment: @Gina: It's not working. Same things happen.

Answer (score 0):

My code combine the class Activity and Touch from the [link](http://vmustafayev4en.blogspot.tw/2011/12/android-imageview-zoom-in-zoom-out.html) and it works. To drag/zoom the ImageView.

Here is a short version that only content code I think is related

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener
{
  ImageView viewmap;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    viewmap = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    viewmap.setOnTouchListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    viewmap = (ImageView) v;
    viewmap.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);

    dumpEvent(event);
    // Handle touch events here...

    viewmap.setImageMatrix(matrix); // display the transformation on screen
    return true;
  }
```

Edit3: xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It's working. The problem is zoom,drag apply whole view (parent view) I need to pinch,drag only image not for whole view

Comment: When use wrap_content the zoom,drag apply one imageView size portion. I can't move image outside of that portion

Comment: maybe becuase my image is bigger than the screen, so the zoom,drag always apply

Comment: When i use wrap_content one rectangle box will appear. I can't move image beyond that rectangle box

Comment: No. I used, it didn't work. When drag bottom page top of image also drag. When i pinch image, view also pinch

Comment: Can you check? I stuck with last 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

I used [imagezoom.jar](http://www.theappguruz.com/blogfiles/imagezoom.jar) , this worked for me.

Steps are:

1. In xml file, replace the normal 'imageview' with 'com.theappguruz.imagezoom.ImageViewTouch'

   ```
       <com.theappguruz.imagezoom.ImageViewTouch
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
   ```
2. Get the image bitmap.
3. Then in onCreate() method of activity, reset image bitmap using below method:

   imgView.setImageBitmapReset(bmp, 0, true);